# Design a data-structure $BankAccount$ that supports the following operations in constant time complexity

Tags: data-structures, lists

**Problem**:
Design a data-structure $BankAccount$ that supports the following operations in $ \underline{\text{constant time complexity}} $. Meaning $O(1) $.

- $Init()$ - initializes bank account $L$ with $0$ dollars.
- $Receive(L,d)$ - adds to the account balance $ d $ dollars.
- $Send(L,d)$ - decreases from the account balance $d$ dollars.
- $BestBalance(L)$ - returns the maximal account balance that had been so far on this bank account.
- $Undo(L)$ - cancels the last operation that had been committed ( out of Send/Recieve ) as if like that operation had never occured.

Pay attention that multiple $Undo$ operations can be done continuously. In addition, the bank account's balance can be negative.

**Attempt**: ( With regards to the context of question above, I've learned about List ADT and it's implementations: linked lists, arrays.)

```
Init():
   L.sum = 0
   L.max = 0
   L.last= ('',0)

Recieve(L,d):
   L.sum += d
   if L.max < L.sum:
      L.max = L.sum
   L.last = ['Recieve',d]

Send(L,d):
   L.sum -= d
   L.last =['Send',d]

BestBalance(L):
   return L.max

Undo(L):
   if L.last[0] == 'Recieve':
      Send(L,L.last[1])
   else:
      Retrieve(L,L.last[1])
```

All of the above implementations run in $O(1)$, there is no list implementation in the above but only an object's and some object field definition.
I'm not sure if the above is correct but I don't understand why, can you please tell me?
Also, I thought of another interpretation to the answer and that is to store all the operations in a list, but I'm not sure.
In anycase, any help will be appreciated!

**Edit:**
Well, my friend has implemented the above data-structure using a linked-list and I've not encountered an example from my class which tells me to implement a data-structure in such a way as to not having to use a list, so these raised my suspicions, so I'm worried that my answer might be wrong. In any-case, from what I've understood, his idea was as follows:

$ \underline{\text{data-structure:}} $ Use circular linked-list. In every node of the list itself, in addition to the value, we'll save another field and in it the maximal value out of all the nodes in the list, we'll call this field $max$.

$ \underline{\text{operation implementation:}} $
Init(L,d) - create an empty linked-list.
Recieve(L,d) - insert $ d $ to the list ( and update its max field ).
Send(L,d) - remove that last element that was inserted into the list ( and update its max field ).
BestBalance(L) - return the value of the max field of the last inserted node.
Undo(L) - removes the last inserted node into the list ( and update the fields of the node preceding it ).

Obviously the above implementation and mine are way off and so, maybe I've misunderstood how I should've approached the problem?. The reason I haven't thought of using a list is because I don't see it as necessary to insert values into a list as we care of the latest values only.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: My conceptual issue is part of the question which I must answer in order to learn. How else can one learn the specifics of a concept if he won't exercise such generalities? I can't learn if I'll leave the attempt as it is since I don't know if it is correct and if there is something else to take a bigger peak on at the problem. I can't seek a teacher since I've already been at his office hours and I've got help to other questions I had ( and he is not admitting any more hours any time soon ) and I've seeked friends but from what I've seen it doesn't seem they're answer is acceptable.

Comment: My teacher didn't teach this subject in an organized way and the whole class struggles with it. Needless to say I've found little information in books regarding extended discussions on ADT's and their implementations, and the few questions that I had seen on stackexchange haven't been able to answer my question because the subject is problem dependent ( as in most dynamic programming problems ) and is scarcely discussed from what I've searched.

Comment: So I don't think it is a "specific question", but rather it is a conceptual question which stems from an example from a pool of examples intended to teach the subject ( as it is such a subject that whoever learns it must learn it in that way, unlike some other subjects/topics where one can mind of to his bussiness for sometime after learning the basics and he'll have the answer later. ). I'm not being hostile, I'm trying to explain that my question's ambient is different from the cases you've unfolded before me.

Comment: read up on stacks ,direct address tables and hash tables and try to approach the problem again.

Comment: @Rinkesh I've read up on them and it didn't help ( I've learned only about ADT lists so far, not including hash tables ). But I asked in the question how I've managed to interpret the question and I'm missing something in the understanding that I don't get from just reading. It is one of those things that you can only learn from someone else's experience and there's no text that can really explain the root of the concept that can directly give a satisfying answer.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 what do you think is wrong with your implementation based on the specification of the problem given to you? Given that you are being specific with Lists, is this something that you are required to use for this problem?

Comment: @Russel I've added an edit to the question. I think I am supposed to implement the data structure using lists because the whole lecture that the exercise above is based about ( the exercise above is only one out of many exercises which I've succeeded ) was about list ADTs and their different implementations. My teacher didn't told me to use what I've learned so far when I've asked him few times this question above. So I came to ask here for some professional help because maybe my Novice eye doesn't see what the professional eye sees.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 please analyze your implementation of the `Undo` operation with respect to performing multiple undo. If you only consider the last receive/send operation, how are you going to perform multiple undo?

Comment: @Russel I think in the question's definition of $Undo$ it was meant to be able to backtrack through all the previous states one by one and "delete" these states, this is supported by sentence in the question which talks about continuous $Undo$ operations. I however, interpreted it as to take the last state and to revert it; meaning if the last state was $X$ and the state before it was $Y$ the $Undo(L) $ would bring me to $Y$ and then if I'd do another time $Undo(L)$, that'd bring me back to $X$, and these are only doable by saving the last state and the one before it.

Comment: Given that you need to be able to revert to some previous state on each undo, this means you must be able to store each state in order of their occurrence, so you can return to the correct state after an undo. From this, hopefully you can see how to use a List to achieve this.

Comment: @Russel Yes, now I understand. Thank you very much!